# Coordinate tool in mathematica fails to arrange the points in a preferred order

Tags: coordinate-transformation, coordinate

I am trying to extract the coordinates from a plot directly by using the Coordinate tool in Mathematica. I show this in figure below.

[image]

The problem is that the arrangement of the coordinates does not correspond to the sequential position of the points on the graph. It appears that the pairs of points in each coordinate are shuffled with commas between in an order irrespective to the order on the image.

This can be seen also when I try to transform these points to a step wise- function
[image]

The code for this is:

```
points = {{831.2353187919464`, 
   266.33641988255044`}, {809.2449664429531`, 
   378.4872168624163`}, {791.6526845637585`, 
   277.33159605704714`}, {785.0555788590605`, 
   389.48239303691287`}, {771.8613674496645`, 171.77790478187933`}}
draupnerfun[t_] := 
 Piecewise[
  Table[{points[[i, 2]], points[[i, 1]] > t}, {i, Length[points]}], 0]
p0 = Plot[draupnerfun[t], {t, 700, 832}]
```

Meanwhile, I add a working example:

```
draupnerpoints = {{-5, 0}, {-4.8, 3}, {-4.5, 1}, {-4.2, 1}, {-4, 
    3.5}, {-3.8, 0}, {-3.5, 6}, {-3.1, 0}, {-3, -5.5}, {-2.8, 
    0}, {-2.5, 6}, {-2.1, 0}, {-1.8, -2.5}, {-1.5, 0}, {-1.2, 
    5}, {-0.8, 0}, {-0.5, -8}, {-0.2, 0}, {0, 18}, {1/2, 
    0}, {2/3, -8}, {1, 0}, {4/3, 4}, {3/2, 0}, {1.6, -4}, {2, 
    3}, {2.5, -3}, {3, 3}, {3.2, -2}, {3.5, 2}, {3.8, -4}, {4.2, 
    0}, {4.5, 6}, {4.8, -5}, {5, 0.1}};
draupnerfun[t_] := 
 Piecewise[
  Table[{draupnerpoints[[i, 2]], draupnerpoints[[i, 1]] > t}, {i, 
    Length[draupnerpoints]}], 0]
p0 = Plot[draupnerfun[t], {t, -5, 5}]
```

How can I correct the first set of points to reflect the step-wise wave-amplitudes you see on the top image?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide Mathematica code!

Comment: *How can we reproduce this?* The community [expects the following](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) from you: 
✅: A clear description of an on-topic problem or goal.
❌: A minimal working *Wolfram Language* code example, formatted, easy to *copy&paste*, in [Raw InputForm](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/RawInputForm.html). 
❌. An example of what you expect as output.
❌. Some proof of minimal *Mathematica* knowledge.
❌. Minimum due diligence: Share how you have searched the site and documentation, your attempts and reasons to believe an answer exists.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann added

Comment: I read your question several times, but I still don't understand it. The coordinates you get are _image_ coordinates (in pixels), not _graph_ coordinates. A particular thing to be careful here is that the origin $(0, 0)$ is in the top-left corner, not bottom-left as is usual for graphs. Secondly, the points are sorted in the order you selected them. So, you get ``{{831.235,266.336},{809.245,378.487},{791.653,277.332},{785.056,389.482},{771.861,171.778}}``. Can you please write down what list do you actually expect to get?

Comment: Thanks Domen! That was important. So I could convert them to the coordinates I like, by subtracting a particular value from each of the coordinates

Comment: Does this mean your problem is solved and this question can be closed? Also, there are some probably some more suitable online tools for extracting data from images, like [WebPlotDigitizer](https://automeris.io/WebPlotDigitizer/).